# Maximum size limit for XMLStringWriter

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I know that there is no such limit defined for XML Doc! In realtime when I am trying to build an XML using XMLStrinWriter, system is erroring out with message `System Out of memory exception`

I don't think I need to provide sample code! I just would like to know the size limit bound by `XMLStringWriter`

Comment: the exception you get says that you ran out of RAM (which is obviously one of the limiting factors) !!!

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561456/xml-stringwriter-empty

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse it is. So what would be the `limit in number` exactly?

Comment: There is no Size limit . Limit is your RAM Capacity.

Comment: @ryadavilli, do you think I should use Flush() here in my code? But here my problem isn't about it being empty! but overloaded!

Comment: Exactly, if you keep flusing in a loop or at some interval it will not get overloaded.

Comment: @halit, are you sure here? RAM is 512 MB! and XML size should not be more than 80 MB. Well other processes do use RAM! so available RAM is too low to be used???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12584295/971839

Comment: @halit,  thanks .. though it is about DOC it clarifies a picture on the consequence..